# Cleanup of answer-related tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, retag-request, meta

These tags all seem to be equivalent, though I'm undecided on which should be the primary tag: [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions), [how-to-answer](/questions/tagged/how-to-answer), [answers](/questions/tagged/answers).

[non-answers](/questions/tagged/non-answers) and [useless-answers](/questions/tagged/useless-answers) should be synonyms of [not-an-answer](/questions/tagged/not-an-answer).
[incorrect-answers](/questions/tagged/incorrect-answers) should be a synonym of [wrong-answers](/questions/tagged/wrong-answers).

Answer (score 4):

I vote for keeping [answers](/questions/tagged/answers), [non-answers](/questions/tagged/non-answers), and [incorrect-answers](/questions/tagged/incorrect-answers) as the *primary* tags.

So:

- [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions) and [how-to-answer](/questions/tagged/how-to-answer) should both be made synonyms of [answers](/questions/tagged/answers)
- [not-an-answer](/questions/tagged/not-an-answer) and [useless-answers](/questions/tagged/useless-answers) should both be made synonyms of [non-answers](/questions/tagged/non-answers)
- [wrong-answers](/questions/tagged/wrong-answers) should be made a synonym of [incorrect-answers](/questions/tagged/incorrect-answers)
  <sub><sup>(This last one I'm more flexible about the mapping, but I think "incorrect" answers is the more technically correct term, and since we're creating a synonym, there's no need to worry about "wrong" being the term that people will more often to think to use.)</sup></sub>